# Is it possible to get the trophy "SHARDCORE" in inFamous 2 while you're still limited to the first part of the city?

Tags: achievements, infamous-2

I ask this because Ive already gotten the trophy for 50% of the Dead Drops. It stands to reason I would probably be able to also get 50% of the Blast Shards (which is how you get the trophy SHARDCORE).

There are civilians running around with shards, but taking them from them is an evil act. Is there a way to get 50% of the shards WITHOUT taking them from the civilians?

This question only applies to the first part of the game, before you've crossed the bridge in the north-eastern part of the city. I'm trying to get the shards in this specific time frame.

I'm really enjoying the game's story, so please leave any comments or answers **spoiler free**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** possible to find 50% of the blast shards without crossing over to the northeastern island, although you'll get darn close.  The ones you can take from civilians in this manner [do not count](http://www.gamesradar.com/infamous-2-blast-shard-and-dead-drops-map-guide/) (spoilers potentially on that page) towards your total for the purposes of this achievement, so you can do this trophy without being "evil" if you so choose.

You might consider part of the rest of the answer spoilers, although I've tried to keep it really vague.  I don't think reading the rest of this answer would be bad, but I don't know if you'd be bothered by it, so I've protected it :)

You may want to wait anyhow as:

> Later you get an ability that helps you find them on the minimap.

The overall blast shard quest contains:

> 305 blast shards, of which [149 are available](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/infamous-2/112751-total-blast-shards-dead-drops-first-island.html) (map on that page, provided to source my answer) on the first island.

Answer (score 0):

You can get accross the brigde into 'floodtown' without it being lowered, although it will be hard to survive over there. Once you have the car jump ability, move a car up to the edge of the bridge either using a blast or kinetic pulse. Then you can jump off the car and reach the other side. 
Voila you're in floodtown. So you should be able to get the blast shards there.